# Splash screen with rEFInd on a MacBook Pro 8.1

Tags: 13.10, plymouth, macbook-pro, refit

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 on my MacBook Pro with rEFIind. The dual boot with OS X works perfectly, Ubuntu works perfectly too but the ubuntu splash screen never displays, only the text startup.

Did I miss something ? How can I see this splash screen again ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to Linux and run the `mkrlconf.sh` script that comes with rEFInd. (If you installed rEFInd from the Debian package, it will be on your path. If you installed rEFInd in OS X, you'll need to extract it from the `.zip` file that you presumably used under OS X.) This will create a file called `/boot/refind_linux.conf`, which will hold additional kernel options, probably including the ones needed to create the splash screen. If that doesn't do the trick, then you can edit `/boot/refind_linux.conf` manually; you probably want to add `quiet splash` to the default (first) set of options in that file.

Comment: It took me 8 months to do the trick but I finally did it. Now a splash screen is displayed on start up but it is actually edibuntu one, whereas I only have normal ubuntu installed. I have no idea how to change it to the normal splash screen.

Anyone knows ?

Thanks.