# How do I add the "atkbd.reset i8042.nomux" parameters to rEFInd?

Tags: configuration, refind

I have a Toshiba Satellite, which has a bug where, after waking from suspend, both keyboard and the touchpad  (edit: this only happens sometimes) don't work.

This can be fixed by editing /etc/default/grub and setting:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash **atkbd.reset i8042.nomux**"

where the bold parameters are the ones I added.

Now, the first time I installed rEFInd it automatically carried over GRUB's settings, included the ones above. However I recently clean installed Ubuntu on a new SSD and one of the first things I did was installing rEFInd; I only remembered later that I needed to modify the line above. 
I therefore tried editing /etc/default/grub after having installed rEFInd, but this seemed to have no effect when using rEFInd.

So, which is the file where I should add *atkbd.reset i8042.nomux* ?

EDIT - sudo update-grub didn't work, the issue is still present

Comment: Did you run `update-grub` after modifying `/etc/default/grub and setting`?

Comment: I've just done it; after that, I tried suspending three times and had no issue. If the issue doesn't show up again I'm going to mark this question as answered (still, if that was really the problem I'm going to feel kind of dumb).

Comment: As someone who has been suffering with a Toshiba Satellite for a long time now, and just found this question, THANK YOU for posting the problem and the solution. I had tried similar options but ended up also messing other things up. This helps and it is great to see someone else had the same symptoms with the same type of computer.

Comment: Since I applied this fix to the grub, however, very often my login password gets wrongly rejected on login. Any idea what causes that or how to fix it?

Comment: No clue, I've honestly never had the issue you mentioned.

Comment: If your Linux Desktop is connected through a switch (mine is DVI KVMP Switch CS1762A), then it might be interfering.  Try connecting keyboard directly to the PC. This solved my keyboard after suspend issue.  I had no need to make changes to GRUB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it; as an answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390774/splash-screen-with-refind-on-a-macbook-pro-8-1#) mentions, additional parameters can be added to the first line of /boot/refind_linux.conf